# How to send Session Variable to next page?

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I am trying to store the session variable to normal variable and using ajax I need to send the value to next page but it gives me an error in ajax code. Below is my code

**index.php**

```
$OTP = $_SESSION['smsgatewaycenterotp'];
echo $OTP;
```

**Ajax Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnonOtp').click(function()
{
   var otp = $('$OTP').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "sms.php",
        method:'POST',
        data:
        {mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
         otp:otp},
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert('OTP Sent');
            console.log(msg);
        }               
    });
});

</script>
```

**Sms.php**

```
    <?php 
include 'send.php';

session_start();



var_dump($_POST);
console.log(msg);
echo $_POST['mobile'];

$OTP = $_POST['otp'];
$number = $_POST['mobile'];

//$text = 'Hi There, how are you?'; 
$sms_api_result = sms_Send($number, 'Please do not share the one time password with anyone. Your One Time password is: '.$OTP,$debug);

?>
```

can anyone help me regarding this issue.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: In your php files have you used `session_start();`?

Comment: Well, where abouts are you referencing `$OPT` in the ajax?

Comment: you don't need to send session variable to another page. create session and you can get session variable in whole website

Comment: Is the `ajax` function in `index.php` file?

Comment: I've answered this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `var otp = $('$OTP').val();` do? If you're expecting that to read the PHP `$OPT` value, it won't, at all.

You're not referencing the PHP `$OPT` value in your ajax.

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sms.php",
    method:'POST',
    data:
    {mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
     otp: <?php echo $OPT; ?>},
    success: function(msg)
    {
        alert('OTP Sent');
        console.log(msg);
    }               
});
```

That means when you POST to `sms.php` it will have `opt:` in the post data, containing the value of `$OPT`.

Your script `sms.php` will be able to read `$_POST['opt']` when the ajax call is made.

*By the way - There are other errors in your `sms.php` such as a `console.log` line - this is a javascript function and will not work in PHP (you're still within the `<?php ?>` tags)*

To test this out modify your `sms.php` to have just this code in it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['opt'])) {
    echo $_POST['opt'];
} else {
    echo "opt not set<br>";
    var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

When you make the ajax request you should get a popup (`alert('OPT Sent'`); in the browser. And if you have the console open it should show the value of `$_POST['opt']`, or a message saying it's not set. If it says  "opt not set" it means this line in your ajax call is not sending the correct value:

```
otp: <?php echo $OPT; ?>
```

However, you can work that out by viewing-source on your page where that Javascript is (`index.php`). If it's blank or has no value, it won't be available in the post data on `sms.php`.

You also have to understand that there is no "next page". The code you posted simply makes an ajax post request from `index.php` to `sms.php`. It will not "load up" `sms.php`, or redirect the user there. The only output you'll see from this is in your browser console because of the `console.log` statement within your ajax success function.

Comment: Andy if we use this <?php echo $OPT; ?> it will not send the data to next page. I have already tried this.

Comment: What's the "next page"? Because all your code does is makes an ajax reuest to `sms.php`. It doesn't redirect anywhere or take the user off their current page.

Comment: In index page i can see the value and I need that value to pass next page called sms.php and capture the value. And the value will be passed in a function. But here in my case the value is not passing and it gives a blank.

Comment: If you run the code I put and view source, what does it say in `opt:` in the ajax code? It should have the value of `$OPT` (because you're `echo`-ing it out to the page). That data is available because you are posting it with ajax to `sms.php`. So in your `sms.php` script you should be able to access it *when the ajax call is made* (obviously it won't work if you just execute `sms.php` as you haven't posted any data to it). But you are not doing anything to redirect or "take the user" to `sms.php`. Your `index.php` script just makes a `POST` request to it, that's all.

Comment: You're mixing all kinds of stuff. You have `console.log(msg);` in a PHP script?! `console.log` is a javascript function and will not work in PHP... So potentially your `sms.php` script won't even run because it has a syntax error in it.

Comment: Modified my answer to clarify

Comment: What you had answered was correct by mixing up the php and javascript. I was not able to capture the value. I have up voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the session value in another page in same website then you can get it by using `$_SESSION` variable. There is no need of ajax. Following are example

**Page 2**

```
session_start();
$session_value = '';
if(isset($_SESSION['smsgatewaycenterotp'])){
 $session_value .=$_SESSION['smsgatewaycenterotp']; // if it is string
}
echo  $session_value; // Out put some value
```

The [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) php built-in function will be check the session value, so if there is value then if statement will be true and the value will be assign to `$session_value` variable other wise that variable will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The Session variable can be reached in every page of your project once you start the session

```
session_start();
```

to understand how to handle the storage use of $_SESSION read more about it in :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php